# JsHint warns about functions inside other files

Tags: javascript, reference, visual-studio-2013, jshint

Using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Premium

I have a javascript file that contains all of my "extensions", lets call this extensions.js

Inside this extensions.js file I have a function. Lets call it RandomFunction.

Inside another javascript file (lets call this RandomFile.js) I make use of the RandomFunction file, and inside browsers this is absolutely fine. However the JsHint is insistent that

```
JsHint (W117): 'RandomFunction' is not defined.
```

Inside of RandomFile.js I have included a

```
/// <reference path="../extensions/extensions.js" />
```

as well as adding a global _references.js to the project.

The references seem to work at least as far as my Intellisense is concerned.

Has anyone any idea how to get rid of the warnings without flat out turning them off?

I'd prefer not to do this as some warnings are genuine.

I am using the WebEssenstials addon.

Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this on a per-file basis by adding the names of the functions the warnings for which you want suppressed to a global line at the very beginning of each file:

```
/* global RandomFunction1, RandomFunction2: true */
```

Alternatively, if you're using a customised `.jshintrc` file you can add the function names to the globals object:

```
{
  "globals": {
    "RandomFunction1": true,
    "RandomFunction2": true
  },
  ... rest of the .jshintrc file.
}
```

There's a lot of information in [the JSHint documentation](http://www.jshint.com/docs/) on both global lines and `.jshintrc` files.

Comment: Excellent, I saw the globals method in the documentation, but did not particularly want to use this as RandomFile2.js may not use the functions inside Extensions.js file... the first solution is perfect for my requirements :)